# Image resize for printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resize, dpi

Can I resize an image with 21cm x 42cm and 1200 DPIs to 24cm x 48cm and 400 DPIs without quality loss?

The reason being is that my scanner max size is 21cm x 42cm and 1200 DPIs. And I need to make an artwork with 24cm x 48cm (bigger than the scanner size).

Thks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

Actually, you end up with a tad bit over 1000ppi.

[image]

Just be certain to **uncheck** "Resample" in the Image Size dialog of Photoshop. Assuming you're using Photoshop.

Comment: Thks a lot Scott!